# Prove that a function is convex when its second-derivative is non-negative

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ be a twice-differentiable function defined on the open interval $M \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Using the following definition of a convex function:

A function $g: I \to \mathbb{R}$ defined on an open interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is *convex* if for all $a,b \in I$ and all $t\in [0,1]$ the inequality

$g(ta+(1-t)b) \leq tf(a)+(1-t)f(b)$ holds,

prove that if $f''(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in M$, then $f$ is *convex.*

There seems to be a couple of posts regarding convexivity and second derivatives, but the proofs are kind of scattered and some seem to use taylor's theorem etc, which I want to avoid. I hope someone can provide a simple and concise proof of this implication.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi(t) = f(x+t(y-x))$. For any $t^* \in (0,1)$ we want to show that
$\phi(t^*) = \phi((1-t^*)0 + t^* 1) \le (1-t^*) \phi(0) + t^* \phi(1)$.

Note that $\phi$ is convex **iff** $t \mapsto \phi(t) - \phi'(t^*) t$ is convex, so we can assume that $\phi'(t^*) = 0$.

We have $\phi(1) = \phi(t^*) + {1 \over 2} \phi''(\xi) (1-t^*)^2 \ge \phi(t^*)$
and similarly $\phi(0) \ge \phi(t^*)$.

Hence $(1-t^*) \phi(0) + t^* \phi(1) \ge (1-t^*) \phi(t^*) + t^* \phi(t^*) = \phi(t^*)$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you would like to see a proof that is more or less intuitive, instead of requiring processing lots of formulas and inequalities. Therefore, let me provide you a rather intuive approach. First and foremost, I'll argue that if $f$ is not convex, there must be a point where the second derivative is negative.

For this, suppose that $f$ is not convex. Then there are $a,b\in I$ and $t\in [0,1]$ such that
$$f((1-t)a+tb)>(1-t)f(a)+tf(b)$$
From this, it follows that $t\in (0,1)$ and $a\neq b$, so without loss of generality we may assume that $a<b$.

The crucial insight is that the above inequality means that the average slope between $a$ and $(1-t)a+tb$ is higher than the average slope between $a$ and $b$, which in turn leads us to a $c$ such that $a<c<(1-t)a+tb$ and $f'(c)>\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

Likewise, there must be a $d$ such that $(1-t)a+tb<d<b$ such that $f'(d)<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

This means that $c<d$, but $f'(c)>f'(d)$, which means that there must be an $x$ such that $c<x<d$ and $f''(x)<0$. This concludes the proof.

I'm leaving out the technical details on the inequalities that lead to $c$ and $d$, but they are based on the fundamental theorem of calculus and the following observation: for any (suitable) function $g$ on an interval $[y,z]$ we have that
$$(y-z)\min_{x\in [y,z]} g(x) \leq \int_y^z g(x) dx \leq (y-z)\max_{x\in [y,z]} g(x).$$